# Suggestions for typewriter font to match Concrete and Euler

Tags: fonts, typewriter

I'm having fun using a combination of Concrete and Euler in some of my documents.  I wonder if anyone has a suggestion about a matching typewriter font?  I've been trying Inconsolata (scaled to .97) but it seems a bit heavy (?dark, maybe?) to my very untutored eye.  Does anyone have another suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

Concrete features heavy serifs and therefore in my opinion does not go together well with Inconsolata (a monospaced font without serifes). I suggest to combine Concrete with Luximono (the latter scaled to 0.86 for matching x-heights).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{beton}
\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{luximono}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\bigskip
\ttfamily

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you; I was not aware of that font.  It is nice looking.  (FWIW, in case someone googles this answer, to me this font matches so much the Concrete body font that a viewer cannot easily tell code from text, so I think I am still looking.)

Comment: Re the issue you just raised: you could add a grey background to the code to set it apart; this is a common solution in books. Or you could increase the kerning of the monospace font, this would help too.