# Good monospace font for code in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, typewriter

I'm currently working on my dissertation and am using Palatino for text with the Euler font for mathematics. As part of my work I'll be presenting quite a few code examples, and was wondering if someone could suggest a good monospace font to go with them. As an alternative I was thinking of using the Concrete Roman and Euler font package (ala Knuth's Concrete Mathematics).

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18715/suggestions-for-typewriter-font-to-match-concrete-and-euler

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I removed 'thanks' from your post since we omit this. Instead, you should [up-vote and accept the answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask), giving the answerer the forum reputation.

Comment: Do you really need a monospace font? Try using a reduced size of Palatino: I find that this often works well, especially if you use the flexible column formatting of the ``listings`` package to maintain column alignment (if needed).  [Palatino Sans](http://www.linotype.com/3201/palatinosans.html) might also be a very nice option (if you use XeLaTeX).

Comment: See http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51/what-font-types-are-good-for-a-technical-document

Comment: Related 1: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/sourcecodepro/

Comment: Related 2: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/firamono/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I personally think that Knuth's typewriter fonts are still very good, an alternative is charter and bera mono if you can get them.

```
 \usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
 \def\rmdefault{bch} % not scaled
 \def\ttdefault{blg}
```

Also check [Different approach to literate programming for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47237/different-approach-to-literate-programming-for-latex) for some typesetting settings for listings.

Comment: If `blg` is a monospaced font, shouldn't `\texttt{....................}\par
\texttt{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.}` produce two equally wide lines?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Not for punctuation against letters.

Comment: Even `\texttt{mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm}\par 
\texttt{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}` is not equal width, where punctuation is not involved.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes its only monospaced between mindnight and 2 am. Also the wind has to come from west

Answer (score 34):

[Inconsolata](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) might be a choice. There is also a [package for TeX support](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inconsolata).

It is a font "designed for code listings and the like, in print," posing itself as a better alternative since many other fonts are designed for screen and not for the high resolutions in print.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\begin{document}
\texttt{This is Inconsolata.}
\end{document}
```

As seen it replaces the `\tt`, but this behavior can be changed.

Comment: It's a nice font, but I find slightly disturbing the fact that the " is slanted to the right... It looks weird when surrounding a string.

Comment: On Windows with TexWorks, you must install the font separately on the machine. Otherwise, this sample is producing an AccessViolation crash in miktex-ttf2pk.exe. I reported the crash here : https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/513

Comment: To get upright quotes in a `\verb` (but not in `\texttt`) you can use the `varqu` option: `\usepackage[varqu]{inconsolata}`. To get them everywhere you need to specify the "stylistic set": `\setmonofont[StylisticSet=3]{Inconsolatazi4}`.